# Asp.net MVC 4 Url Resource cannot be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my Index page I am generating url using the following

```
@foreach(var c in ViewBag.cities)
{
   <li>@Html.ActionLink((string)c.CityName,"somepage",new{city=c.CityName, id=c.Id})</li>
}
```

Which generated urls for every city in the following format

```
localhost:55055/1/city1
localhost:55055/2/city2
...
```

where 1,2 are Id and city1, city2 are CityName

I have configured the route as

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "CityRoute",
            url: "{id}/{city}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "somepage", id = UrlParameter.Optional, city = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

The `somepage` action method in Home Controller:

```
public string somepage(int id, string city)
{
  return city + " " + id;
}
```

Even I tried this

```
public string somepage()
{
   return "Hello";
}
```

but it results in `Resource cannot be found`

I tried putting breakpoint in `sompage` which is never hit.

Any suggesstions

**Update**

As pointed out by @KD in comments below I changed the routes order and placed above mentioned rule above all rules. I also changed the method

```
 public ActionResult somepage(int id=0, string city="")
 {
    return Content(city + " " + id);
 }
```

Now the behavior changed and the default rule

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

is not used for normal index page. Instead this use is used since the breakpoint in method `somepage` is hit and If I put `http://localhost:55055/2/cityname` in the browser, the page does display id and cityname. But now default route is not used for application home `http://localhost:55055/`

Comment: Please update your title with your specific problem..

Comment: Please ensure you are adding routes in correct order. The route you've added should be at the top of your default route.

Comment: Also try this action method public ActionResult somepage(string id, string city)

Comment: @KD thanks. yes they are in correct order

Comment: @KD I should say partially in correct order. Now that I placed this rule above all. The behavior is different. The default route is no more used for the normal index page instead the new rule that I added (mentioned above) is used. I changed the method to `somepage(int id=0, string city="")`

Comment: Route should have some specific identifier. basically you route should have some prefix as the default route and your's is having same patter. it would work well if you change your pattern to this..
url: "Citylookup/{id}/{city}",... or something like this
And your url should be localhost:55055/Citylookup/1/city1... You can specify routename while providing ActionLink.. try it

Comment: @KD could you please check the updated post and suggest.

Comment: I tried your code and so far everything works fine. No error.

Comment: @JobertEnamno really?? But in my case the default route is not used for index page. I cannot browse the home/index page using `localhost:55055`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pattern of your new route and pattern of default route is almost same hence it will always create conflict to match those routes .. change your route to following

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "CityRoute",
            url: "CitySearch/{id}/{city}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "somepage", id = UrlParameter.Optional, city = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

i.e. add some prefix to your pattern so it can get easily identified.. like "CitySearch"
and then mention your route name while providing Action link for it..

Or if you don't want to add prefix to it then do the following thing and it will work like a charm..

For your CityRoute add a Route Constraint for Id which will check if the ID field is Integer. for normal URLS it will return false and hence your default route will get evaluated ... try this...

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "CityRoute",
            url: "{id}/{city}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "somepage", id = UrlParameter.Optional, city = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new {id = @"\d+"}
            );
```

This is the Regular Expression Constraint.. Put this route at the top and check.

Comment: +1 yes I agree because all the other links now point to `somepage`. Definitely a conflict

Comment: at `"\d+"` it says unrecognized escape sequence

Comment: really sorry for this I searched web and tried adding @ before you suggested, it resulted in another error saying `Named argument specifications must appear after all fixed arguments have been specified'. Just searching again to resolve this issue.

Comment: take help from this article to specify constraint for your route.
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-route-constraint-cs

Comment: specify constraint like this as you have specified argument name for each one, constraints: new {id = @"\d+"}

Answer (score 0):

As you have not defined Action it won't be called thus error is coming

Try this,

```
public ActionResult somepage(int id, string city)
    {
        return Content(city + " " + id);
    }
```